# UITableViewCell in iPad master detail UISplitView does not automatically respond to orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, interface-builder

In xcode 4.2, if you set up a new project for both iPhone and iPad and choose to create a new iOS "Master-Detail Application" Xcode will set up a lot of template code for you. The iOS "version" of the application has a different simpler storyboard. I want the detail view of my application to also be a Table View controlled by a table controller and I want the cells of this table view to automatically resize with an orientation change. The problem is that while this works for the iPhone version of the application, it doesn't work for the iPad version.

Pre-conditions:

If you edit the detail view on the iPhone storyboard so that it contains a Table View Controller and define the table view to contain a single prototype cell - set the prototype cell to be of a custom type and add some subviews to it then define those subviews with auto resize properties (for example two buttons - one fixed to the left side of the view, the other to the right margin of the view). Do the same for detail view of the iPad storyboard (which of course is contained in a more complex split view controller arrangement).

Double check all the view controllers have resize view from NIB selected (which they do by default) and all the views have Autoresize Subviews selected.

Expected:

When the application is compiled for either iPhone or iPad, in both cases the table cell and it's subviews should resize on orientation change.

Actual Result:

On the iPad version of the app the table cell does not re-layout to match the changed size of the UITable view. The table cell on the iPhone version of the app behaves as expected.

It's clear the chain of subview layout for nested views is broken such that re-layout subviews is not occurring or getting called all the way down to the table view cell when an orientation change occurs. Anyone know if this can be fixed in Interface Builder or if not what code is required to re-establish the chain? I know how I can fix this using willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: , in my own custom subclass of UITableViewController but I'm not sure doing it this way is clean and I would prefer not to have partial automation of orientation changes with scraps of code providing workarounds for stuff I think it should be possible to automate.